Why does differencing White Noise induce autocorrelation of $-0.5$?
I am curious about the following problem. Let's have a variable given by white noise,
$$y_t \sim \operatorname{NID}(0,1).$$
Let's say we difference it,
$$\Delta y_t = y_t - y_{t-1}.$$
And now, if we measure the ACF of $\Delta y_t$, we get that the first lag is autocorrelated by $-0.5$.
The question is: Why $-0.5$, specifically?

This is an immediate (and simple) consequence of the bilinearity of covariance.

For notational simplicity, let
$$X_t \equiv \Delta Y_t.$$
By definition,
$$
\text{Corr}(X_t,X_{t-1}) = \frac{\text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-1})}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_t)}\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_{t-1})}}.
$$
Here,
\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}(X_t) &= \text{Var}(Y_t-Y_{t-1}) \\
&= \text{Var}(Y_t) - 2\text{Cov}(Y_t,Y_{t-1}) + \text{Var}(Y_{t-1}) \\
&= 1-0+1 \\
&= 2.
\end{aligned}
and the same for $\text{Var}(X_{t-1})$. Thus
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_t)}\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_{t-1})} 
&= \sqrt{\text{Var}(X_t)}\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_{t})} \\
&= \text{Var}(X_t).
\end{aligned}
Also,
\begin{aligned}
\text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-1}) &= \text{Cov}(Y_t-Y_{t-1},Y_{t-1}-Y_{t-2}) \\
&= \text{Cov}(Y_t,Y_{t-1}) - \text{Cov}(Y_t,Y_{t-2}) - \text{Cov}(Y_{t-1},Y_{t-1}) + \text{Cov}(Y_{t-1},Y_{t-2}) \\
&= 0 - 0 - \text{Var}(Y_{t-1}) + 0 \\
&= 0 - 0 - \text{Var}(Y_{t}) + 0 \\
&= 0-0-1+0 \\
&= -1.
\end{aligned}
Thus,
$$
\text{Corr}(X_t,X_{t-1}) = \frac{-1}{2} = -0.5.
$$
